# Is it possible to remove or delete logs from console based on the timestamp for a .net application during runtime?

Tags: .net, azure-functions, serilog

Is it possible to remove or delete logs from the console that are older than a specific number of minutes (n=1,2,3...) during the runtime of an ASP.NET Azure Function project? If so, how can this be achieved?

In my Azure Function project, I have integrated **Serilog** to write logs to the console during each HTTP trigger. As the application progresses, the number of logs increases. However, I want to automatically remove logs with a certain timestamp from the console during the application's runtime. I attempted to achieve this by using the `.Filter.ByIncludingOnly()` function during the **Serilog** configuration in the `Program.cs` file, but I haven't seen any results.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Serilog;

var hostBuilder = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults() 
    .ConfigureServices(service =>
    {
        var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .WriteTo.Console()
        .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(entry => entry.Timestamp.Date == new DateTime(2023,6,11))
        .CreateLogger();

        service.AddLogging(lb => lb.AddSerilog(logger));
    })
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
    {

    });

var host = hostBuilder.Build();
host.Run();
```

Comment: "The console" is just `stdout`/`stderr`: it's a write-only stream, so you cannot remove or delete entries from it, because those "entries" don't exist in-memory: it's all just rendered-out to plain-text (and maybe ANSI terminal codes for colors and whatnot) so it loses its structure - and once the user clears the back-buffer in their terminal-emulator or console-window then it's gone-for-good.

Comment: Rather than using console-logging, you should log to files (such as structured-logging using JSON-per-line files) which is built-in to Serilog: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Sinks.File

Comment: `.Filter.ByIncludingOnly()` won't _remove_ any logged events, it merely stops them from being logged in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to automatically remove logs with a certain timestamp from the console during the application’s runtime.

It is not possible to remove or delete logs from the console based on the timestamp for a  **.NET**  application during runtime.

- If you need more control over logging and the ability to remove or manipulate logs based on their timestamp, consider using a logging framework or a dedicated logging tool that provides advanced logging features and log management capabilities.
- It is recommended to use file-based logging, such as structured logging using JSON-per-line files, as suggested by @Dai. Serilog provides built-in support for logging to files using various sinks, such as  `Serilog.Sinks.File`. By logging to files, you have more control over the log entries, including the ability to filter and manipulate them based on specific criteria.

Try this below configuring  **Serilog**  to log:

```c
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Serilog;

var builder = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .WriteTo.File("logs.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day) // Specify the log file name and rolling interval
            .CreateLogger();

        services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
        {
            loggingBuilder.ClearProviders(); // Clear any default logging providers
            loggingBuilder.AddSerilog(logger, dispose: true);
        });
    });

var host = builder.Build();
await host.RunAsync();
```

- You can retain the log entries and perform various operations, such as filtering and deleting logs based on their timestamp or other criteria, as needed.

**output:**

[image]

**Second approach:**  Custom logging

- By registering the  `ILogStore`  and  `InMemorySink`  with the dependency injection container, you can access and manipulate the logs stored in memory. You can call  `RemoveLogsOlderThan`  to remove logs from the queue that are older than a specific timestamp.
- A custom  `InMemorySink`  is implemented to store the logs in an in-memory queue  `ConcurrentQueue<LogEvent>`. The  `ILogStore`  interface defines methods to add logs to the store and remove logs older than a specified time.